# How to correctly resolve a promise within promise constructor

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

```
const setTimeoutProm = (delay) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(() => res(delay),delay))
```

I want to do something like,

```
const asyncOpr = (delay) => { 
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
    //update delay for some reason.
    const updatedDelay = delay * 2;
    setTimeoutProm(updatedDelay).then(res => {
      resolve(res);
    }).catch(err => {})
  })
}
```

```
asyncOpr(2000).then(() => alert("resolved")) //this works
```

This works as expected, but I am not sure if this is correct way of doing this or is there any better way of doing this ?

Comment: Why the `asyncOper` function? Can't you just use `setTimeoutProm`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, actually the way you do it is an [antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it).

You can just return a promise from the function:

```
 const asyncOpr = (delay) => { 
  return setTimeoutProm(delay);
 };
```

If needed, a Promise could also be returned from inside a `.then`:

```
 doA()
   .then(() => setTineoutProm(1000))
   .then(() => doB());
```

Or it can also be awaited inside an async function:

```
  async function asyncOpr(delay) {
    //...
    await setTimeoutProm(delay);
    //...
 }
```